# Restoring xfce4-power-manager to default settings

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, laptop, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

After unchecking "Handle display power management" in Xfce Power Manager, the system locked up. (I was troubleshooting an issue with the laptop where it would lock up upon the display turning off.)

Upon rebooting, the system behaves normally until a password is entered in the greeter. At this point the desktop will fail to load and the system will become unresponsive.

Is there any way via TTY that I can re-enable this option?

I've attempted restarting the power manager instance and then starting an xsession but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have managed to resolve this myself -

To turn the above option back on, edit the below xml file -

```
~\.config\xfce4\xfconf\xfce-perchannel-xml\xfce4-power-manager.xml
```

In the line -

```
<property name="dpms-enabled" type="bool" value="false"/>
```

Change the 'false' to 'true'.

Comment: While running & logged in, `xfconf-query` might be useful to change settings too, editing the file doesn't take effect until after logout/login